# Singularities of magnetic field in Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, singularities

Consider the relativistic Lorentz force equation given by
\begin{equation}\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{m\dot{x}}{\sqrt{1-|\dot{x}|^2/c^2}}\right)= E(t,x)+\dot{x}\times B(t,x).
\end{equation}
Here,  $E$ and $B$ denote respectively the electric and magnetic fields and are given by
\begin{equation}
E=-\nabla_x V-\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}, \qquad B=\mbox{curl}_x\, W,
\end{equation}
with $V:[0,T]\times \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, $W:[0,T]\times\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ $C^1$-functions.

Usually $V$ and $W$ are assumed to be singular at one ore more points. As an example, at my last class of physics I there were assumed to be $V:[0,T]\times \mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\} \to\mathbb R$, $W:[0,T]\times\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R^3$ as the lecturer provided an example of $E, W\sim 1/|x|^a$ with $a>1$.

Actually, the lecturer stated also that $W$ could also have a ring/circle of singularities instead of a single point.
As it was not motivated at all and no examples have been provided, I have left these two questions:

1. In which cases $W$ has a ring/circle of singularities instead of a single point? An example would be very appreciated;
2. It could happen that $V$ (instead of $W$) has a ring/circle of singularities? Why it seems that $W$ has a privileged role in having a ring/circle of singularities?

Any example and reference will be very welcome.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ The comments suggest to consider a potential generated by a ring of charge. Anyway, as this potential is something like $V=kq/r$ (see e.g. this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potlin.html), Hence $V$ is not defined at $r=0$ (or equivalently $z^2 +R'^2=0$) which is a single point and not a ring of singularities. To have a ring of singularities, I expect to have a potential like
$$V(t, q)=\frac{kq}{x^2 +y^2-1}$$
so that $V$ is singular at $x^2 +y^2 \neq 1$ which, though it is not a ring, is the edge of a circle.

Am I wrong with that idea?

Comment: Perhaps a ring of charge?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves could you please give an explicit example? I can not see it.

Comment: Vector potential $W$ is singular on circle in case there is current running in that circle. $V$ is singular on circle in case there is charge concentrated on that circle. This is obvious from the Coulomb formula, and there is similar formula for vector potential of current (implied by the Biot-Savart law and the Coulomb gauge).

Comment: @JánLalinský I am not convinced of what you are saying. The potential for ring of charge is given by $V=kq/r$ (as in there http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potlin.html), then $r$ it is not defined at $r=0$ which is a single point which is not a "circle/ring of singularities". To be singular at  circle/ring of singularities I expected something like $x^2 +y^2 \neq 1$ (for example). Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Look at the figure again - $r$ is distance from $P$ to the closest element of the circle. So $r=0$ for all points $P$ on the circle.

Comment: The *off-axis* electrical potential for a ring of charge is more complicated than the on-axis result you quote from Hyperphysics. You can see from the diagram you link that $r$ is not the usual spherical coordinate; the page should say that the potential along the $z$-axis is $kq/\sqrt{z^2+R^2}$, to remove the impression that $r=0$ is a single point.

Comment: @JánLalinský thank you for the comment. May I ask you why one choose the closest element on the circle and not the farthest or one in the middle of the ring?

Comment: @rob thank you. May I ask you if one can also have a magnetic potential for a ring charge? I mean, the same examples works for the vectorial potential $W$?

Comment: rob is right, the hyperphysics page gives potential only on the centered line, and $r$ is distance to the circle. General formula valid for all points of space is much more complicated and I don't have it, however, it is obvious from the general Biot-Savart formula that potentials diverge on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Singularities in the electric field correspond to discontinuities in the electric potential, which occur for charge distributions whose density is infinite in one or more dimensions.  These include

- point charges, with field $E \sim 1/r^2$
- line charges, with field $E \sim 1/r$
- surface charges, with field $E \sim \text{constant}$

Volume charges don't have these singularities. I suppose you could argue that the constant field on either side of a surface charge has a discontinuity rather than a singularity, but if you do then a mathematician will ambush you at a restaurant and talk about differentiability or entire functions some other nonsense.

The magnetic field has the same $\int_\text{volume} \frac{\text{stuff}}{r}$ that the electric field has, and so it has singularities for the same types of low-dimensional current distributions.  There isn't such a thing as a "point current," but line currents and sheet currents are both useful approximations in many circumstances.  (The magnetic field due to a moving point charge is a little more complicated, because it includes a time-varying electric field; a line current can be electrically neutral.)

In the question and the comments, you discuss a ring of charge (which would generate a magnetic field if it were a *rotating* ring).  To see the singularity here, imagine finding the field very close to the ring.  If your distance from the ring is much smaller than the ring's radius, the curvature of the ring becomes irrelevant to the problem, and the field reduces to the field due to a line.  Textbook-level arguments, such as [the one you link to](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potlin.html), can help you find the field on the axis of the ring by exploiting the symmetry of the system.  But the three-dimensional electric and magnetic fields due to a rotating ring of charge are quite complicated.  I don't have my copy handy, but I recall even the famously complete graduate-level textbook by Jackson only finds the various approximations.